# Getting Parse Error <this.props.activeRouteHandler/>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Know how to get [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) working with ReactJS?

It's throwing errors in browser console for me. My code is below. I installed `npm react-router` and using a basic server i.e. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000` which works fine for React app that doesn't have the Router code.

Error in console is `Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 18: Unexpected token .
<this.props.activeRouteHandler/>`

I think its that my app.js can't find the react-router module, but maybe a RequireJS issue (I include it from a CDN in my index) ???

```
Directories
/index.html
/scripts/app.js
/node_modules/react-router
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="scripts/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Routes = require('../node_modules/react-router/modules/main').Routes;
var Route = require('../node_modules/react-router/modules/main').Route;
var Link = require('../node_modules/react-router/modules/main').Link;

var About = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <h2>About</h2>;
  }
});

var Users = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Users</h2>
        <this.props.activeRouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var User = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.params.userId}</div>
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="users">Users</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="user" userId="123">User 123</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <this.props.activeRouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent((
  <Routes>
    <Route handler={App}>
      <Route name="about" handler={About}/>
      <Route name="users" handler={Users}>
        <Route name="user" path="/user/:userId" handler={User}/>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
), document.body);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I upgraded to react-router 0.5 and I was even using react 0.11. I changed  to {this.props.activeRouteHandler()} and it started working. I marked this as a "todo" to look into though.

No matter what you do, don't give  up. It works great!  We were using backbone router before and this react router is such a blessing compared to our old setup!

Also with your directory setup you can change your requires to just "require('react')" and use browserify to build your app and required dependencies into a single js asset.  Everything else looks good.

Comment: You need to upgrade the JSX transformer, which is where that error's being thrown.  `npm install --save reactify@0.14.x` assuming you're using the browserify transform

Comment: With Browserify & Reactify now I get a blank page in browser, React isn't rendering: `browserify -t reactify app.js -o ../build/app-brow.js` My script tag is now: `<script type="text/javascript" src="build/app-brow.js"></script>`

Comment: I stop/started my web server to get a clean start, using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000`. And now I get this `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: renderComponent(): Invalid component descriptor. This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React.`

Comment: Ah, it also looks like you maybe missing your "var React.require('react')" in your app.js. Since you said on GitHub you are using browserify and reactify, you can remove the script tags in your index.html. After you have executed browserify, your output should contain all of your code plus all of your required modules. Look at your output file to make sure.

Comment: @Randy, yes that's it, I thought the script tag would work so I could load ReactJS from a CDN. I guess this means using react-router I can't load ReactJS from a CDN?

Comment: Correct.  By the time you uglify and the web server gzips your js file, it is really pretty small.

Answer (score 3):

Namespace support in JSX was introduced in React 0.11.0.  You have 0.10.0.  Change the script tags to use 0.11.0.

```
<script src="http://fb.me/react-0.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.11.0.js"></script>
```

With the 0.10.0 and below you would have done this:

```
var activeRouteHandler = this.props.activeRouteHandler;
return <activeRouteHandler />
```

Comment: What do you mean by Namespace support in JSX? Got any 1 liners to quickly explain. Thanks -))

Comment: I just mean the `<a.b.c>` being allowed.