# What am I doing wrong with my react-router?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use `react-router` to route my app, but I keep getting a `404` on my routes.  Here is my `routes` files:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar />
                <div className="container">
                    <this.props.activeRouteHandler />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var routes = (
    <Routes location="history">
        <Route path="/" handler={App}>
            <Route path="/users" handler={LilyApp} />
            <Route path="/user-detail" handler={UserDetail} />
        </Route>
    </Routes>
);

React.renderComponent(routes, document.getElementById('lily'));
```

I see my `Navbar` when I navigate to the root `/`, but I don't see the main part of my app on either route.  What am I missing to route my app?

Comment: To clarify, the `LilyApp` and `UserDetail` handlers aren't activated when you visit `/users` and `/user-detail`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Parse Error <this.props.activeRouteHandler/>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028188/getting-parse-error-this-props-activeroutehandler)

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.activeRouteHandler` is a function, so replace this:

```
<this.props.activeRouteHandler />
```

with this:

```
{ this.props.activeRouteHandler() }
```